# Xcode iOS simulator acting weird

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I just started out learning iOS programming using Xcode. I'm having a slightly annoying problem: Whenever I build and run an app in the iOS Simulator the device used by the simulator is always an iPad as default though I'd like it to be iPhone. This behavior is very strange considering that I've specified the target device in Xcode to be "iPhone Retina (3.5-inch)".

[image: http://gyazo.com/aa759ed8d4d3f2eb73274d1eae1aa3d3]

I know that I can change the device from the iOS Simulator menu "Hardware", but it's annoying to have to do it every time I'm launching an app. I've also tried changing the target device from inside of Xcode, but that doesn't do it either.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: 3 ways you can change it,
From simulator's hardware menu..
From Top bar of xCode..(By Selecting device or simulators)
And from your xCode target Project Select Device iPhone .. 
it just simple. You tried lot..

Comment: By the way welcome to iOS Programming.. give reply..

Comment: That isn't an iPad. It's screen is 640 px wide. It's the 3.5 inch retina iPhone.

Comment: and Set size of your simulator by selecting Window Menu > Scale > What ever you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

⌘ + 3 = Normal Size

⌘ + 2 = Halfway

⌘ + 1 = What you're seeing right now